# Date conversion format Java to DB different format

Tags: java, sql, oracle, date

I'm making a code in java that executes an Oracle database procedure
The format I have to put there in the procedure when I run through the database is dd/MM/yyyy.
I have to send this date from my java code using a CallebleStatement setDate with the date yyyy-MM-dd (which is the Date format in java)
When this CallebleStatement is executed, will it transform the date I'm sending to the database format, or will it write to the Java format?

EDIT:
It is basically this:

```
if(types[1].compareTo("DATE") == 0) {//procedureValues[i] = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
    cs.setDate(i+1, Date.valueOf(procedureValues[i].trim()));
}else {
    cs.setObject(i+1, procedureValues[i].trim(), SQLTypes.valueOf(types[1]).getTypes());    
}
```

And yes, the procedure expects the DATE format

Comment: Are you aware of `SimpleDateFormat`? If you provide a sample of your code, we might provide an answer

Comment: Is the parameter for your DB procedure defined as a date, or as a string? If it's a date (as it should be, and as your use of setDate implies) then you don't need to worry about 'format'.

Comment: @procra Please don’t suggest the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: There are some misunderstandings in your question. You don’t have to pass the date in any particular format. And you don’t have to use `setDate()`, Since JDBC 4.2 the recommended way is to use `setObject()` and pass a `LocalDate` to it. And not worry about its format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, a `DATE` is a binary data type composed of 7 bytes (century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second). It **ALWAYS** has those components and it **NEVER** stores a format.

> When this CallebleStatement is executed, will it transform the date I'm sending to the database format, or will it write to the Java format?

If you are using `CallableStatement.setDate()`, it will transform it to the binary values required by the database. It will **NOT** store it in an (easily) human readable format.

If you want to see how the database stores the value then you can use:

```sql
SELECT DUMP(your_date_column) FROM your_table;
```

When you read the value from the database then the client application (in this case, Java via the database driver) will read the binary values from the database and will convert it to a representation suitable to the client application.

If you read it in a different client application then the binary values will be converted to the appropriate representation for that client application; so two different client applications (for example, Java and SQL/Plus) may display the same binary date value with different formats.

Comment: This was exactly what I believed was happening. And in the end, the error was a business rule and not formatting the date.... Thank you for your patience and for the well-explained answer.